# Can we apply the concept of 'fresnel number' to multiple slits?

Tags: diffraction

As I know, there is a concept of 'fresnel number (NF)' to represent the level of diffraction. Normally, we can call Fresnel diffraction if the NF is much smaller than 1, and Fraunhofer diffraction if the NF is much larger than 1.

And in all of the textbook that I read, the NF is explained in the case of a single slit. However, we can assume a case of multiple slits. It also makes some diffraction pattern by changing the distance from the facet of slits.

I want to describe the diffraction pattern of multiple slits according to the distance. Can I use the concept of NF in the case of multiple slits? Or should I introduce new FOM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Page 21 of this article](http://wyant.optics.arizona.edu/webMathematica/myprograms/fresnelZones/FresnelDiffraction.pdf) has a discussion of Fresnel diffraction for a double slit which may help you?